# Getting 11200 Http retrieval error while calling the system call back in Twilio

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, twilio

I want to get the delivery status of the message send by Twilio. So I used the system call back. But it throws an error i.e;Request to StatusCallback URL was not successful. and status is 404. How can I get the status of message and 200 response from the Twilio. This is my Webhook code. I used the node.js :

```
const http = require('http');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/MessageStatus', (req, res) => {
  console.log("entered inti");
  const messageSid = req.body.MessageSid;
  const messageStatus = req.body.MessageStatus;

  console.log(`SID: ${messageSid}, Status: ${messageStatus}`);
  res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
  res.sendStatus(200).end();
});

http.createServer(app).listen(1337, () => {
  console.log('Express server listening on port 1337');
});

exports.TwilioSMSWebhook = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

How to solve this issue?[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Express server is listening on port 1337, are you telling Twilio to send to this specific port in the statusCallback URL (otherwise the default port for https is 443)? Also, on another note, the statusCallback should return a 204 or a 200 with empty TwiML, as detailed below.

Status Callbacks
https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/twiml#status-callbacks

You can always test our your URL using a tool like Postman, to see why it may be returning a 404 - Not Found.

Comment: Hi Alan, I have called the Webhooks url as system call back url.

Comment: Hi, not sure I understand your answer, can you clarify?

Comment: The issue was resolved. Thank you for your response.